# How to modify one element of a class without bothering the rest with the same CSS class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to Select one instance of messageCase and expand it. This is the jquery and javascript that I have so far. right now this changes every instance of messageCase and adds the animation properties i want. How can I make it so this does not happen to all instances of messageCase?

also I am under "use strict"; conditions.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var aTag = $("div.messageCase").id();
    var divTarget = $("div.messageCase")

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        if (target.is(aTag)) {
            if (divTarget.hasClass("messageCase")) {
                // divTarget.removeClass("messageCase");
                divTarget.addClass("messageCase messageCaseAnimation");
            }
        } else {
            divTarget.addClass("messageCase");
        }

        if (!target.is(divTarget))
        {
            $(divTarget).removeClass("B");
        }
    });

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is simple, you target something else in addition to the class. It could be where the element is regards to `this`, or an index, or another class, or surrounding elements, children, or .. well anything really

Comment: my problem is that my messageCases are all the same so Their is nothing unique to identify to them. I can add Id's but then I have to create them dynamically and I'm not sure how to do that otherwise This would be easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `click` method you assign the clicked element to `target`, so it appears you could do:

```
target.addClass("messageCase messageCaseAnimation");
```

Here's a simplified example of your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divTarget = $("div.messageCase")

  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    target.addClass("messageCase messageCaseAnimation");
  });

});
```

And here's a full demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divTarget = $("div.messageCase")

  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    // Remove the messageCaseAnimation from all
    divTarget.removeClass('messageCaseAnimation');
    
    // Add the messageCaseAnimation to only the clicked
    target.addClass("messageCaseAnimation");
   
  });

})
```

```css
.messageCaseAnimation {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messageCase">
  Case 1
</div>

<div class="messageCase">
  Case 2
</div>

<div class="messageCase">
  Case 3
</div>

<div class="messageCase">
  Case 4
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this simplified version first and all messageCase's Expand with the animation. I tried this more complicated version hoping something different would occur... bad decision i know. I just one instance of messageCase on click to animate without causing all others to do the same.

Comment: Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/d7gkxwh7/) showing it in action.

Comment: Works! Thanks Again!